# How do I get the name of the QCombobox which is triggering def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):

Tags: python, qcombobox

I have two Qcomboboxes in my Ui_MainWindow. How do I determine which of them is triggering the def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):??? When I printed self.**class**.**name** it returns "Ui_MainWindow"...I want the name of the Qcombobox within that window???

```
def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
   
    print(self.__class__.__name__)
    id_ = self.cboDebtor.itemData(index, IdRole)
    # or
    # id_ = self.model.item(index).data(IdRole)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a method connected to a slot, you can use `self.sender()` inside that method to retrieve the widget that sent the signal.

So if you want to display the name of the widget which sent the signal, do it like this:

```
def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
    print(self.sender().objectName())
```

Given your description, you probably want to do something like:

```
def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
    sender_name = self.sender().objectName()
    if sender_name == 'foo':  # QComboBox 1's name
        self.do_something()
    elif sender_name == 'bar':  # QComboBox 2's name
        self.do_something_else()
    # etc
```

Comment: Thank you...that worked!